# Weblogic 10.3.5.0 SAML2 SSO -> Error 403 / Error 401

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

i configured 2 weblogic domains with managed servers as seen in [Biemond's blogpost](http://biemond.blogspot.de/2009/09/sso-with-weblogic-1031-and-saml2.html)
i used the

> DemoIdentity & DemoTrust

i enabled SSL and
added to the web.xml of my deployed app:

```
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myrealm</realm-name>   
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
    <description>These are the roles who have access</description>        
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

and mapped this role to a principal (a user i added in both weblogic servers/domains) in my weblogic.xml file.
But it doesn't work.
Everytime i get

> Error 403 -- Forbidden

and in my second sample app i get

> Error 401--Unauthorized

anyone else with this problem? or maybe a solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you went to `myrealm->Realm Roles->Edit Global Role` and added your user to the Admin role conditions?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i did this already but it didn't solve the problem. Error 401 / 403 persists :(